# Connection Closed Gracefully requesting from last.fm using Indy TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy10, last.fm

I'm trying to use the [last.fm api](http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search) using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component. When I send a request, I keep receiving `Connection closed gracefully` without receiving any data. However, when I copy the same URL from the component (directly to the clipboard) into a web browser such as Chrome or Firefox, it works perfectly fine.

I'm trying to implement the `album.search` call, and am trying to `GET` the data from this sample URL:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?format=json&api_key=MY_API_KEY&method=album.search&album=believe&limit=30&page=1

[This request is documented here](http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search)

I have a helper function to concatenate the common URL structure:

```
function TLastFm.ApiUrl(const Method: String): String;
begin
  Result:= Format('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/%s/?format=json&api_key=%s&method=%s',
    [FVersion, FKey, Method]); //FVersion = '2.0', FKey = my API key
end;
```

And then I make the actual call like this:

```
var
  S, R: String;
begin
  S:= ApiUrl('album.search')+'&album='+Album; //Album = 'believe'
  S:= S + '&limit=30&page=1';
  Clipboard.AsText:= S; //Used to paste into browser to test
  FHTTP.Request.UserAgent:= 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; JD Test)';
  R:= FHTTP.Get(S); //<-- Connection closed gracefully
  // ...
end;
```

How do I make this call successfully using Indy's `TIdHTTP`?

Comment: What's different between the HTTP request your program sends and the one the browser sends? I'd use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to check. I think there might be more specialized programs for that nowadays.

Comment: A good example of high-level ispection for modelling Firefox behaviour is Firebug extension.

Comment: Fiddler is a good one to use, Wireshark is good as well though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created an account and got my API Key. I set up these constants:

```
const
  FVersion = '2.0';
  FKey = 'MYAPIKEY';
  Album = 'believe';
function ApiUrl(const Method: String): String;
```

I have the IdHTTP component set on the form where you are manually creating it though.

```
procedure TForm1.btnGetRequestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S, R: String;
begin
  S := ApiUrl('album.search')+'&album='+Album; //Album = 'believe'
  S := S + '&limit=30&page=1';
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; JD Test)';
  mem.Lines.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(S);
end;
```

I got a memo back full of json results.

EDIT:

I have done a few more subsequent tests and it seems that if there is a space in the search keyword you will get the Connection Closed error.

If you try:

```
Album = 'believe '; // Connection closed gracefully
```

If you try:

```
Album = 'believe'; // I get a json response back
```

Comment: Face+Palm... I had a space in the textbox where I typed in the search terms. I hadn't gotten to the URL formatting part yet because I had no clue I accidentally had a space there.